# RegEx: Capturing a group in a section that may not exist

Tags: regex

I am parsing a file that has various personal information on it, and only information that exists is in the file even though there are potential fields for much more.  For example:

[other stuff]
Home Phone:
[home_phone]
Mobile Phone:
[mobile_phone]

So the phone section could look like any of the four following examples:

```
Home Phone: 
(111) 222-3333
Mobile Phone: 
(111) 222-3334
```

or

```
Home Phone:
(111) 222-3333
```

or

```
Mobile Phone:
(111) 222-3334
```

or

```
[nothing]
```

I'm trying to use the following regex snippet to match home phone, and it's not matching anything at all.

```
(Home\sPhone.\r\n(?<hphone>\(\d\d\d\)\s\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d))?
```

(I know there's a lot to improve, but I'm not very good with these so I'm just trying to hash it out via brute force before I start optimizing.  Hence the repetition in the phone number matching pattern.)

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the end of a line often varies depending on system/program, you could use something like `[\r\n]+` to cover some additional bases - `\n` or `\r` occuring one or more times.

So your expression would become:

```
(Home\sPhone.[\r\n]+(?<hphone>\(\d\d\d\)\s\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d))?
```

And then you can start to compact the expression a bit more, e.g:

```
(Home\sPhone.[\r\n]+(?<hphone>\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}))?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the system you are using terminates lines with `\r` or `\n`, but not both.

Removing the `\n` works on http://regex101.com/r/iZ9qR9